# Flutter ListView, Maintain Offscreen Items

Tags: flutter, listview

I am using a `ListView` in specific circumstances to display a known, limited number of items. In this case, images.

**Is it possible to stop items of a specific `ListView` or widget to keep drawing offscreen?**

--

In this specific case, I am using `clipBehavior: Clip.none` to simplify padding logic. However, the side effect is the images in my `ListView` pop out of existence when they pass a certain boundary, despite being 'onscreen'.

Code Sample:

```
Widget _sample() {
    return ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            // The image strip
            ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              controller: _scrollController,
              // Clip.none allows image to display beyond parent padding.
              // However, doesn't prevent children of this list vanishing 
              // once they leave the bounds of the list itself.
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: List.generate(
                _data.length,
                (index) => _buildItemBody(index: index),
              ),
            ),
            // Other elements of this list child
          ],
        ),
        // More Children...
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could you please share some code sample?

Comment: Added a code sample to demonstrate how the `padding` and `clipBehaviour`, as well as how the inner `ListView` children will disappear.